# Using Zapier to Get New Email from Gmail Account

Tags: zapier

I am using `Zapier` webhook to fetch data from the Inbox of my Gmail account but I am not getting priority of the mail from Gmail. How will I get priority data from Zapier Webhook?

I am fetching all information but I am not getting information about email priority. I want to get email priority.